# Support needed with Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I keep getting this error
401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.
Request Details

```
immediate=false
response_type=token
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay911247760
state=882158738|0.380667456
origin=http://www.myserver.dev
include_granted_scopes=true
client_id=733677449783-holhtgvu994e0oavk4hud3mupbu71b2f.apps.googleusercontent.com.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
```

That’s all we know.

I have created a project Proj1 
  set the product name to Proj1
  enabled the relevant APIs
  Client ID
    733677449783-holhtgvu994e0oavk4hud3mupbu71b2f.apps.googleusercontent.com
 Javascript Origins
        http://www.myserver.dev
  Redirect URIs
        https://www.example.com/oauth2callback
  API key
    AIzaSyDBt5-gE9xJOGIqamru46cw-RIipKbsI2o

Is there any other parameters that I need to set.

Answer (score -1):

```
string state = "882158738|0.380667456";
string scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly";
string redirect_uri = "APIAddress";
string GoogleClientID= "your ClientID";

string oauthUrl = string.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" +
                                   "scope={0}&state={1}&redirect_uri={2}&response_type=code&client_id={3}&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline",
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("scope"),
state,
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(redirect_uri ),
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(GoogleClientID));

return oauthUrl ;
```